# How to end while loop for integer gathering array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, while-loop

I am wring a program that askes the user to give any value they want as long as it is a whole number, and that value will be placed in a array. They can do this asmany times as they would like, until they add -1 to the array. I am having a hard time figurig out how to get the loop to end.
My code:

```
    int i = 0;
            while (i != -1) {
                System.out.print("Enter a positive whole number, enter '-1' to stop:");
                s = scan.next();
                if (i ! = -1)
                 intElements.add(i);
```

I think the issue is in my if conditional. Not sure what the correct way to write out the logic would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change:

```
s = scan.next();
```

To:

```
i = scan.nextInt();
```

If you only want POSITIVE ints to be added, then also change your `if` statement to:

```
if (i > 0)
```